# Table of contents wrong when setcounter{page}{1}

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, roman-numerals

I'm working on a document, and I don't want numbering on my front page, so I placed a `\thispagestyle{empty}`.
Now at my ToC, I use `\setcounter{page}{1}`. But my document still counters the ToC page as page number 2 when I use `\thepage` in the footnote.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{EMG Document Process Tool}
\rhead{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=3cm]{HeaderPicture.png}}
\lfoot{Manual}
\rfoot{J. Doe \\{Pagina \thepage}}
\graphicspath{/home/bitbucket/stage}
\author{John Doe}
\date{Januari 2015}
\title{Manual\\{\large EMG Document Process Tool}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Azm.png}
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagebreak
\section{Install}
text
\section{text}
text
\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{text}
text
\pagebreak
\section{text}
text
\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\pagebreak
\section{text}
text
\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\pagebreak
\section{text}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Programma.png}
\pagebreak
\section{text}
\subsection{text}
text
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{VerschilMeting.png}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We are guessing around when not seeing some minimal but compilable code. Please add that to your question!

Comment: you have to set the counter after your page break. Then it works.

Comment: but the \thepage from the footnote still says page 2 on the toc page. and 3 on the install page. where in toc it says it's in 2.

Comment: After changing the \pagebreak into \clearpage the page numbers are right, but the ToC is wrong, and i 1 page ahead of the numbering...EDIT: Nevermind, I had to recompile it. It's good now, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `\setcounter{page}{1}` before `\tableofcontents` and it is better to use `\clearpage` than `\pagebreak`. Further, you will get a warning from `fancyhdr` regarding the head height. To silence that you need to add `\setlength{\headheight}{33pt}` (`33pt` is obtained from that warning).

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   %% remove demo
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{EMG Document Process Tool}
\rhead{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=3cm]{HeaderPicture.png}}
\lfoot{Manual}
\rfoot{J. Doe \\{Pagina \thepage}}
\setlength{\headheight}{33pt}    %%<------ added
\graphicspath{/home/bitbucket/stage}
\author{John Doe}
\date{Januari 2015}
\title{Manual\\{\large EMG Document Process Tool}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Azm.png}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage  %% better than \pagebreak
\section{Install}
text
\section{text}
text
\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{text}
text
\pagebreak
\section{text}
text
\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\pagebreak
\section{text}
text
\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\pagebreak
\section{text}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Programma.png}
\pagebreak
\section{text}
\subsection{text}
text
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{VerschilMeting.png}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Harish made some important points above, for example about the
headheight.

The title on it's own page, including a picture. That sounds
suspicously like a titlepage that you can trigger by using the
global option `titlepage`. I the example below i used package
`titling` to add a picture after the date because titlepages are
unfortunately fixed and not customizable by default.

Looking at all those `\clearpage`s, i think you might be more
satisfied with a report class, that provides `chapter`s that
always start on a new page. You might wanna have a look at this.

I beat you already know about the floating behaviour for figures
and tables that make your document look so much smoother.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{EMG Document Process Tool}
\rhead{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=3cm]{HeaderPicture.png}}
\lfoot{Manual}
\rfoot{J. Doe \\{Pagina \thepage}}
\setlength{\headheight}{33pt}
\graphicspath{/home/bitbucket/stage}
\author{John Doe}
\date{Januari 2015}
\title{Manual\\{\large EMG Document Process Tool}}
\usepackage{titling}
\predate{\begin{center}}
    \postdate{\par\vspace{5ex}\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Azm.png}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Install}
text
\section{text}
text
\begin{enumerate}
    \item text
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{text}
text
\pagebreak
\section{text}
text
\begin{enumerate}
    \item text
\end{enumerate}
\pagebreak
\section{text}
text
\begin{enumerate}
    \item text
\end{enumerate}
\pagebreak
\section{text}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Programma.png}
\pagebreak
\section{text}
\subsection{text}
text
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{VerschilMeting.png}
text
\end{document}
```